# Create keyword label via Google Ads API

Tags: google-ads-api

does anybody know if there is a way how to create a label for a keyword using Google Ads API? It can be done using the web interface and apparently it could be done using the Adwords API, but I can't find a way how to do it using Google Ads API so I don't know if it's a feature which they didn't implement or if I'm blind.

Their documentation says

> Labels allow you to categorize your campaigns, ad groups, ads, and keywords, and use those categories to simplify your workflow in a variety of ways.

which would suggest that it CAN be done, however below on the same page it states

> You can assign labels to your campaigns, customers, ad groups, criteria, or ads.

No word about keywords. I am working with PHP / Laravel and I am using their official php package for the API communication. The package has classes like CampaignLabelOperation, CustomerLabelOperation, AdGroupLabelOperation, etc. but NO "KeywordLabelOperation".

Anybody have a clue if I just can't find it or whatever I could do? Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, *Keywords* are *Ad Group Criteria*. Therefore, you'd need to use the [`AdGroupCriterionLabelService`](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v7/AdGroupCriterionLabelService)'s `MutateAdGroupCriterionLabels` to create a keyword label.